# aligning input-group-addon in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align the input-group-addon text to be on the left rather than the right side of a textbox.

if I use this:

```
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon" style="font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;"text</span>
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
</div>
```

it works, but if I exchange the second and third rows of code:

```
<div class="input-group">
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
<span class="input-group-addon" style="font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;"text</span>
</div>
```

the addon doesn't move to the other side of the textbox but rather moves to the far left of the page.

your help would be very much appreciated.

*I'm using right-to-left alignment.

Comment: I don't think Bootstrap supports RTL without an external library. You can see here how it changes http://www.bootply.com/GnW6ozmIfZ

Comment: You have a typo, you need to close the span tag, before you write "text"